# add titles to images in ad media in pages and posts

Tags: images, media-library

When editing pages or posts you can press the add media button. This shows a grid of all your images but it does not display the image names. I have lots of similar images and I would like a image name there to be able to pick the right image.  Does any one know how to do that?

Comment: Use javascripts (/+jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Clicking on the image will display all of the information about it, including the file name, on the right.

Answer (score 0):

I am aware of that, but that still means  you have to click through several images before you can find the one you are looking  for